# navbar-toggler isn't working/bootstrap navbar doesn't toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am using vuejs to create the component of a navigation bar, which uses bootstrap and does not collapse. Bootstrap and jquery I installed them with npm, and I'm not sure if it could be the cause, since in other components I did everything works fine. The problem appears when I am trying to use the mobile version or the size of the window on PC shrinks

Navbar.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <nav class="navbar custom-nav fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <router-link class="navbar-brand" to="/">My page</router-link>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to="/" class="nav-link">Home</router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to="/productsPage" class="nav-link">Products</router-link>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to="/about" class="nav-link">About</router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <a
              class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#login"
            >Be an artist</a>
            <a
              class="btn btn-outline-info border-0 mx-2 my-2 my-sm-0"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#miniCart"
            >
              <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>
            </a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  components: {}
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar.custom-nav {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    background-color: white !important;
  }
}

.btn-outline-success {
  background-color: #ffa7a7;
  border-color: #ffa7a7;
}

.btn-outline-success:hover {
  background-color: #ffbcd9;
  border-color: #ffbcd9;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

i {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.fa-shopping-bag {
  color: #353753;
}
.fa-shopping-bag:hover {
  color: #c9fdff;
}
</style>
```

Dependencies code (package.json):

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^7.14.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-firestore": "^0.3.30",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vue-stripe-elements-plus": "^0.3.2",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.10.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },
```

I have seen other StackOverFlow questions before where the problem occurs and many suggest using the tag to put jQuery and CDN Bootstrap in the index.html file that is in the public directory of any Vuejs project, which in my case has not worked.

Comment: are you loading `jquery` before `bootstrap`?

Comment: Yes, it's being loaded first in the index.html file and even in the main.js file where the "global dependencies" are being declared